# jQuery Full Calendar Default View Setting

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery Full calendar.

But I am not getting how to set the week view as Default view in full calendar.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'basicWeek'
    aspectRatio: 1.5
});
```

Ref: [FullCalendar Available Views](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/)

**Edited:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'basicWeek'
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thing more how can i set the week tab active when i have set week as default view?

Comment: Left timing bar and gridline are still not visible when we week view is set as default

Answer (score 3):

Use the `defaultView` option:

```
$('#myCalendar'-.fullcalendar({
     defaultView: 'basicWeek'
})
```

- [defaultView option](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/defaultView/)
- [Available views](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/)

Comment: This answer is a useful resource. +1 for posting.

Answer (score 3):

in v5 is
initialView: 'timeGridWeek'

Answer (score 2):

To get a calendar with a view of the week and hours:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this **agendaWeek**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
theme: true,
header: {
left: 'prev,today,next',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
.....
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
},
initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
```

With newer version defaultView will not work, try initialView, make sure the value matches the options listed under your headerToolbar.

Answer (score 0):

As for Version 4, use

```
defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
```

or

```
defaultView: 'dayGridWeek',
```

reference: 
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultView

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      ...
});
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialView

work for me in ver 5.11.0